# Display Serial Number as Roman letters in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

need to display serial no as roman letters(i,ii,iii,iv etc) in my crystal reports. I have the serial number captured as record number (1,2,3,4...).so what i have to do for it in crystal report.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `Roman()` function provided by Crystal Reports

Answer (score 1):

I can't take much of the credit; I simply ported the code from [this VB Helper article](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_roman_arabic.html) into Crystal, but it was a fun exercise:

```
NumberVar iCounter := 0;
Local StringVar ch := "";
Local NumberVar result := 0;
Local NumberVar new_value := 0;
Local NumberVar old_value := 0;
Local StringVar temp := "";

temp := UpperCase({?@Roman});

old_value = 1000;

For iCounter := 1 To Len(temp) do
(
    // See what the next character is worth.
    ch := Mid(temp, iCounter, 1);

    if ch = "I" then new_value := 1
    else if ch = "V" then new_value := 5
    else if ch = "X" then new_value := 10
    else if ch = "L" then new_value := 50
    else if ch = "C" then new_value := 100
    else if ch = "D" then new_value := 500
    else if ch = "M" then new_value := 1000;

    // See if this character is bigger
    // than the previous one.
    If new_value > old_value Then
        // The new value > the previous one.
        // Add this value to the result
        // and subtract the previous one twice.
        result := result + new_value - 2 * old_value
    Else
        // The new value <= the previous one.
        // Add it to the result.
        result := result + new_value;

    old_value := new_value;
);

// Format the number without commas or decimals
ToText(result, 0, "");
```

Simply replace my `{?@Roman}` parameter placeholder with your variable, and you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix it [enter image description here][1]

```
<https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=887691>
```

or

```
<https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1613334>
```

and

```
<https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_UaulmICtM&list=TLPQMTUwMjIwMjMRAYZJzCsXDQ&index=6>
```

specifically: at crystal report

TH1: Fomula fields/new/"**nameabc**"/enter/"**Roman(GroupNumber)**"/ ctrl+S/and pull it out

TH2: Fomula fields/new/"**nameabc**"/enter/

```
 select GroupNumber

 case 1 : "   I"

 case 2 : "  II"

 case 3 : " III"

 case 4 : "  IV"

 case 5 : "   V"

 case 6 : "  VI"

 case 7 : " VII"

 case 8 : "VIII"

 case 9 : "  IX"

 case 10 : "   X"

 case 11 : "  XI"

 case 12 : " XII"

 case 13 : "XIII"

 case 14 : " XIV"

 case 15 : "  XV"

 case 16 : " XVI"

 case 17 : "XVII"
default : ""
```

/ ctrl+S/and pull it out

But it really doesn't help t so there will be this 3 case (t improved from link 2-3) it can apply to the 3rd or even 10th group of headings

TH3: ex: (you want to create a text message for group 3)
Formula fields/new/"**nameabc**"/enter/
"

```
WHILEPRINTINGRECORDS;
GLOBAL NUMBERVAR INTSTTGRTEST;
INTSTTGRTEST :=0;
```

/ ctrl+S/ drag it out and put it in heading group 2 and hide it (= right click/format field/common/ check Suppress/ok) you can go to link 3 to see

Formula fields/new/"**nameabcd**"/enter/
"

```
WHILEPRINTINGRECORDS;
GLOBAL numbervar INTSTTGRTEST := INTSTTGRTEST + 1;
stringvar y;
STRINGVAR ARRAY X := ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K", "L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X ","Y","Z"];
if INTSTTGRTEST <= 26 then (
redim preserve X[INTSTTGRTEST];
y := X[INTSTTGRTEST]
);
y;
```

/ ctrl+S/and pull it out and place it at group 3

and the alphabet can be whatever we want. ex:

```
X := ["I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX","X","XI" ,"XII","XIII","XIV","XV","XVI","XVII","XVIII","XIX","XX","XXI","XXII","XXIII"," XXIV","XXV","XXVI","XXVII","XXVIII","XXIX","XXX","XXXI","XXXII","XXXIII","XXXIV","XXXV","XXXVI" ,"XXXVII","XXXVIII","XXXIX","XL","XLI","XLII","XLIII","XLIV","XLV","XLVI","XLVII","XLVIII"," XLIX","L"];
```

or

```
X := ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
```

hope it can help you

```
enter code here  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeBBQ.png
```